# Can't install flatpak on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, software-installation, installed-programs, 22.04

I have a fresh installation of ubuntu 22.04 and nothing was touched. I'm following the steps on the flathub website but I'm getting this annoying error and won't let me do it. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
https://launchpad.net/~flatpak/+archive/ubuntu/development provides newer prereleases of Flatpak from its development branch.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~flatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable.gpg with fingerprint 5C6D153A17C02C337EF6C663B8B9D41229DFA5F5
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease                       
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu jammy InRelease                
Err:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 443]
Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly not an annoying error. It is an important error that warns you that you are attempting to add a repository to Ubuntu 22.04, that is not suited for that version and thus could break your system if the system did not warn you.

If you read the instructions on the Flathub website again, you will notice that there is no need to add a repository to install Flatpak on Ubuntu. It is included in the standard ubuntu software sources, and can be installed with the command

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

That already enables flatpak. Next you can add the flathub repository:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

which simplifies installing flatpaks from that repository from the terminal.

Optionally, you can install gnome-software and the flatpak plugin. That will allow you to install flatpaks from Gnome Software, and will cause them to be updated automatically.

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

Comment: If you are on a live session, [add the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407058/flatpak-has-no-installtion-candidate-on-ubuntu-22-04).