# flatpak has no installtion candidate on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, flatpak

As i executed

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

On my live usb booted ubuntu 22.04
The terminal throws the error message as follows

```
Package flatpak is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsolete, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
xdg-desktop-portal
```

and yes I tried updating and upgrading ubuntu 22.04 with

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

But no use.
Please help!

Comment: If you are using a Live USB, probably the universe repo is not enabled. Run `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, then `sudo apt install flatpak`.

Comment: It worked thaks bro

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then update and upgrade

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

Now try installing flatpak

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

The universe repo was not enabled in 22.04 while running on live usb as @Lorenz Keel said in comment